# How to create a custom renderer in F# for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms, customization

I don't know where to place this line:

```
[<assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof<TransitoCDMX.Main.FbLoginPage>, typeof<FbLoginPageRenderer>)>] do()
```

In C# it is usually placed before the namespace in this way:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(TransitoCDMX.Main.FbLoginPage), typeof(FbLoginPageRenderer))]
```

Comment: Assembly attributes usually go in a separate file. But it should be OK to do just what you do in C#. Have you tried it? Did it work? How did it fail?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin The problem is that in F# you can't reference a type that hasn't been declared.
On C# you would place the assembly attribute right before the namespace where the custom renderer is defined.

Comment: So place it in a separate file that comes after the definition. Or place it in the same file right after the definition. I don't see a problem.

Comment: Probably you are right, but I was getting an error at runtime anyway, maybe a bug from Xamarin... So I decided to reserve the use of F# only for the logic, and use C# on everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-"The problem is that in F# you can't reference a type that hasn't been declared. On C# you would place the assembly attribute right before the namespace where the custom renderer is defined."

-"So place it in a separate file that comes after the definition. Or place it in the same file right after the definition. I don't see a problem."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/attributes